# plotBand of highcharts not accessibile

Tags: highcharts, accessibility, react-highcharts

I am trying to implement accessibility(keyboard navigation on hover state). When I hover the plot band I can see the tooltip values as given by moverover event. But when I tab into it I can see that the borders are highlighted but no data of hover state(ie.the tooltip) is shown. I have attached fiddle for the same.

```
           events: {
              mouseover() {
                /* Show usage number on hover for first plot band */
                this.label.element.innerHTML = 'RED'
              },
              mouseout() {
                this.label.element.innerHTML = '';
              }
           }
```

PS: I have even added zIndex to the plotbands and fill-opacity:0 for the series.
Any help?
https://jsfiddle.net/Delfin_/bad9hfzt/85/

Comment: It wouldn't work. Your custom tooltip is attached only for the mouseover event which is not triggered while hovered by the tab. Why don't you use the Highcharts tooltip? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/njbdp3a4/

Comment: @SebastianWędzel sure. I found that on documentation but I wanted the plot bands to be accessible. http://jsfiddle.net/Delfin_/eo681sj9/3. Sadly the plot bands dint get highlighted through accessibility hence I used the series to highlight it but the numbers displayed on the mouseover event are not showing up through keyboard accessibility

Comment: once again - it wouldn't work that way. If you want to use the Highcharts accessibility to you need to use the implemented method - like hovering the point which triggers the tooltip. Hovering plotBands with using tab doesn't trigger the mouseEvent (where your custom tooltip is attached) so please use Highcharts method and do it via using series.